# Adding attribute of type Array[long] from existing attribute value in DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.0 and have a use case where I need to convert the attribute type of a column from string to Array[long].

Suppose I have a dataframe with schema :

```
root
 |-- unique_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2 : string (nullable = true)
```

DF :

```
+----------+---------+
|unique_id | column2 |
+----------+---------+
|  1       |  123    |
|  2       |  125    |
+----------+---------+
```

now i want to add a new column with name "column3" of type Array[long]having the values from "column2"
like :

```
root
 |-- unique_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- column3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

new DF :

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|unique_id | column2 | column3 |
+----------+---------+---------+
|  1       |  123    | [123]   | 
|  2       |  125    | [125]   |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

I there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `withColumn` and `array` function as

```
df.withColumn("column3", array(df("columnd")))
```

And I also see that you are trying to change the `column2` from `string` to `Long`. A simple `udf` function should do the trick. So final solution would be

```
def changeToLong = udf((str: String) => str.toLong)


val finalDF = df
  .withColumn("column2", changeToLong(col("column2")))
  .withColumn("column3", array(col("column2")))
```

You need to import [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) library too as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Comment: hi @Ramesh , did you check this on df ?
I got this error "error: not found: value array"

Comment: you need to `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`

Comment: great to hear that @Ram, and thanks for accepting and upvotes :)